# Bootstrap small device order of the grid row

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, mobile, row

On desktop the order of the grid row is:
Text | Picture
Picture | Text
Text | Picture

On mobile this becomes:
Text
Picture
Picture
Text
Text
Picture

Is there any way to change this order on mobile? 
to for example: 
Text 
Picture 
Text 
Picture 
Text 
Picture

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `pull` `col-md-pull-*` to your text.

so your text would be in the left and when it small, it will be in the top.

Or

You can use `push` `col-md-push-*` to your picture.

so your text would be in the right and when it small, it will be in the bottom.

check this out http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-offseting